# How to Open the Audit report file(.json)?

Tags: json, google-chrome-devtools, audit

I am using Chrome Dev Tools. I use it to generate an audit report, then save it as a .json file. Then, how to reopen it in Chrome? I cannot find a way to open the .json file in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Open-AudIT cleverly checks an association's system and stores the arrangements of the found gadgets.

An incredible revealing structure empowers data, for example, programming permitting, [setup changes](https://www.kgrnaudit.com/company-incorporation-in-dubai/), non-approved gadgets, limit usage and equipment guarantee status to be removed and investigated.

Open-AudIT Enterprise accompanies extra highlights including Business Dashboards, Report sifting, Scheduled revelation, Scheduled Reports and Maps.